# Add Parameter to Aura Components Apex Controller

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript, parameters, promises

I am relatively new to aura components and am having trouble understanding the interconnectivity between files when using parameters in functions.  I added the "enrollmentId" parameter along with code to to the "getOOSPOptions" function which did not take anything in before.  I ran tests and have the apex controller functioning as it should using test data, but I would like to get the aura component files working as well.  I want the record Id (oosp) to be able to fill the parameter for the "getOOSPOptions" method in the apex class.

I added these lines to the helper and thought it would work since "v.oospId" is brought in like this in other methods

```
var enrollmentId = component.get("v.oospId");
            var action = component.get("c.getOOSPOptions");
            action.setParams({
                "enrollmentId" : enrollmentId
            });
```

I am currently getting a "There was an error." toast and "List index out of bounds: 0 - OOSP.js:505" in the console at runtime.

Thanks!

**Apex Controller**

```
    @AuraEnabled
    public static OOSPOptions getOOSPOptions(String enrollmentId) {
        Id enrollmentIdVal;
        if(!String.isBlank(enrollmentId)) {
            enrollmentIdVal = Id.valueOf(enrollmentId);
        }
        List<PicklistOption> cipOptions = new List<PicklistOption>();
        List<PicklistOption> stateOptions = new List<PicklistOption>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult cipFieldResult = Experiential_Enrollment_Detail__c.CIP_Type__c.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> cipPLE = cipFieldResult.getPicklistValues();
        for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : cipPLE)
        {
            cipOptions.add(new PicklistOption(f.getValue(),f.getLabel()));
        }             
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult stateFieldResult = Experiential_Enrollment_Detail__c.State_List__c.getDescribe();
        
        List<Experiential_Enrollment__c> currentOOSP = [SELECT Id, Name, Enrollment_State__c 
                                  FROM Experiential_Enrollment__c
                                  WHERE Id= :enrollmentIdVal];
        
        String enrollmentState = currentOOSP[0].Enrollment_State__c;
        
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> statePLE = stateFieldResult.getPicklistValues();
        System.debug('Enrollment State: '+enrollmentState);
        for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : statePLE)
        {
            try{
                if(f.getValue().contains(enrollmentState)==false){
                    stateOptions.add(new PicklistOption(f.getValue(),f.getLabel()));
                }
                
                //Manually check for Virginia due to it being contained in West Virginia
                if(enrollmentState=='Virginia' && f.getValue().contains('West Virginia')){
                    stateOptions.add(new PicklistOption(f.getValue(),f.getLabel()));
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.debug('An exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
            } 
        }

        return new OOSPOptions(cipOptions, stateOptions);
    }
```

**JS Controller**

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
        var lastYear = new Date().getFullYear() - 1;
        component.set("v.currentYear",lastYear.toString() + ' - ' + currentYear.toString());
        //get Layout, build Reporting Period combobox
        helper.getInstitution(component, event, helper).then(institution => {
            component.set("v.institution", institution);
        }).catch(error => {
            helper.toast(
                "There was an error.",
                error.message,
                "error",
                "sticky",
                5000
            );
        }).then(() => {
            helper.getOOSPOptions(component, event, helper).then(options => {
                component.set("v.cipOptions", options.cipOptions);
                component.set("v.stateOptions", options.stateOptions);
            }).catch(error => {
                helper.toast(
                    "There was an error.",
                    error.message,
                    "error",
                    "sticky",
                    5000
                );
            });
        }).then(() => {
            helper.getReportingPeriodOptions(component, event, helper).then(rptPeriods => {
                component.set("v.reportingPeriods", rptPeriods);
                if(rptPeriods.length > 0) {
                    component.set("v.selectedReportingPeriod", rptPeriods[0].value);
                }

            }).catch(error => {
                helper.toast(
                    "There was an error.",
                    error.message,
                    "error",
                    "sticky",
                    5000
                );
            });
        });
    },
```

**JS Helper**

```
getOOSPOptions : function(component, event, helper) {
        return new Promise($A.getCallback((resolve, reject) => {
            var enrollmentId = component.get("v.oospId");
            var action = component.get("c.getOOSPOptions");
            action.setParams({
                "enrollmentId" : enrollmentId
            });
            action.setCallback(this, function(response){
                var state = response.getState();

                if(state === "SUCCESS"){
                    // console.log(JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
                    resolve(response.getReturnValue());
                } else if(state === "ERROR"){
                    var errors = response.getError();
                    console.log(errors[0].message);
                    reject(errors);
                }
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
        }));
    },
```

Comment: the error is most likely happening from a blank "enrollmentIdVal" you should add a check for that and proper error handling and user feedback

Comment: @glls I still get the error when I hardcode the enrollmentIdVal to the Id to test it so I am not sure where the error is coming from

Comment: where are you hardcoding it?